# Ask Ubuntu meta page title says just "Ubuntu Meta" and another title issue

Tags: bug, user-interface, meta, site-attributes

[image]

If one looks at the title of any page on AU Meta, then will see that the title is:

> [Page title] - Ubuntu Meta - Stack Exchange

when IMO it should say "Ask Ubuntu Meta". Even worse, on the [ask page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask), once a few words are typed and suggestions for similar questions given out, the title is:

> [Title] - Ubuntu - Stack Exchange

which doesn't even have a meta designation. Is this by design, or a bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ask page has the correct title for me. Bug on your end?

Comment: No... Type a few words into the title and get the suggestions, and it' wrong again.

Comment: Nope, worked again for me.

Comment: @Flabricorn did it offer a few suggestions below the title and was there text in the body you entered? Also, can you reproduce the issue on all other pages as to being only Ubuntu meta?

Comment: The title when I view a meta question in Chromium is: *Question Title* - Ubuntu Meta - Stack Exchange

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Right--I posted that comment help confirm the bug. Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: @EliahKagan No problem.

Comment: I reproduced both, the second seems to happen when you click directly in the body of the question without first typing anything for the title, then the title switches out.

Comment: and it seems that it happens on the normal "ask question" page, as "Ask a Question - Ask Ubuntu" changes to "- Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange" http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Reproduced on MacOS X 10.6.8, Safari Version 5.1.7, Opera Version 12.02, Firefox 14.0.1, Camino 2.1.2, On Xubuntu 12.04, Firefox 15.0, Opera 11.64, Chromium 20.0.1132.47, but not in Links 2.6 ;)

Comment: @mateo_salta In regard to your last comment, what is Links? Is it like Lynx?

Comment: yeah, a text based browser, meant to be funny since it has text only.